# windows 10: launch windows terminal as administrator from task bar in one click and use single icon

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, windows-terminal

I can get it to run as admin by creating the shortcut to `wt.exe` and checking the `Run as Admin` checkbox for the shortcut. But it duplicates icons on the taskbar once the app is opened. There is one icon for shortcut and one icon for Windows Terminal.
If I click Pin to Task Bar on the new Windows Terminal icon, it will create some special type of shortcut that has the `Run as Administrator` option grayed out:

[image]

Is there a way to make it:

1. start with one click on the Task Bar icon
2. use elevated privileges
3. use the single Task Bar icon instead of creating the duplicate

Answer (score 7):

> Use the single Task Bar icon instead of creating the duplicate.

Unfortunately, there is no way to elevate the permissions of a UWP application, doing so doesn’t actually do anything since the permissions of a UWP application are purposefully limited when launched.

However, on Windows 10 there is an acceptable workaround:

> 1. Right-click on the Desktop or a folder and select **New > Shortcut**.
> 2. Type in the following location textbox and click next:
>
>    c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c start /b wt
> 3. In the name textbox, type in **Windows Terminal** and click **next**.
> 4. Right-click on the newly created shortcut and select **Properties**.
> 5. Click the Advanced button and check **Run as Administrator**.
> 6. In order to make the shortcut look identical you can download the Windows Terminal
>    [icon](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/res/terminal.ico)
>    file and set the icon of the shortcut within the Properties window.
> 7. Right-click on the created shortcut and select **Pin to Taskbar**.

It’s worth pointing out this method doesn’t appear to elevate the permissions of Windows Terminal, you are actually just elevating the permissions of default profile within Windows Terminal.  This method is only valid for Windows 10 at this time.

Ironically, on [Windows 11](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/open-elevated-windows-terminal-as-administrator-in-windows-11.556/), it’s as simple as launching Windows Terminal with “run as Administrator” since it’s built-into Windows 11.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a shortcut on your taskbar you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> click and it will open as Administrator.

Comment: This is an amazing combo to know about - thanks for sharing