# Start Command Prompt always as admin through Windows Terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, administrator, command-line-arguments, windows-terminal

How can I make Windows Terminal always run Command Prompt as admin so I can issue elevated commands?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [windows 10: launch windows terminal as administrator from task bar in one click and use single icon](https://superuser.com/questions/1667463/windows-10-launch-windows-terminal-as-administrator-from-task-bar-in-one-click)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - I will edit my answer to make it clear, the solution is to upgrade to Windows 11, while the workaround is the process I described

Comment: @TheUnknown - You cannot actually elevate the permissions of a UWP application.  Additionally, your question, is specifically about Windows Terminal.  Windows Terminal is an exception to that rule.

Comment: @Ramhound I just tried the shortcut method with Spotify (another UWP application I installed from Windows Store) and it works.

Comment: I question if the permissions of Spotify were actually elevated, but if it was, then the application implements [`allowElevation`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) which was introduced in 1809.  I don't make a habit of attempting to elevated UWP applications to that of an Administrator since in the past it did very little.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, the Spotify process was actually elevated. So it depends on whether the application uses `allowElevation` in the manifest.
Technically, you CAN edit the application's manifest files to allow elevation but that's beyond the topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command prompt will always run as admin work if the host terminal is elevated which it doesn't by default so you'll need to do it manually.

Make a new shortcut anywhere, add this link to field `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe`, click ok, set name `Terminal`, and click ok.
Then go to properties and click "Advanced" and check "Run as administrator".

This will make the shortcut always run the terminal as admin.
You can also Pin to Start and/or add it to the `C:\Windows` directory so it can be run as a "Run Command" and through Windows Explorer

Optionally, download and set the original icon: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/terminal/master/res/terminal.ico

**Pointed out by @Ramhound:**
If you would like to use this method for other UWP applications, it's a little different story. In our case, the windows terminal uses `allowElevation` in its manifest file. Not all of the UWP applications use that and do not require such elevated privileges. If you really want a UWP application that doesn't support to allow elevation by default, you would need to mess with its manifest files.
[Follow This Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481825/how-to-change-manifest-in-executable)

**Edit**:
As pointed out by @user1686, `-verb RunAs` will have no effect until Terminal is elevated and if it is, you don't really need the argument as it automatically launches elevated command prompt.

Comment: If the host terminal runs as admin, is the cmd.exe arg actually still needed?

Comment: Just realized that its not.

I first used the argument and it worked for a while for some reason and then it won't open the elevated command prompt so I had to set Terminal to always run as admin.

If the host terminal is elevated, it automatically elevates command prompt. Thanks for pointing out!